# custom title and description of physical web notification

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jsx, eddystone, eddystone-url

Reply from : https://github.com/google/physical-web/issues/595

For example, I am transmitting www.starbucks.com
http://www.starbucks.com as the URL.

My phone looks for physical web pages and say it detects www.starbucks.com
and shows it to me in my physical web present in my chrome.

As a user, this is how it will appear to me presently

[image]

» Now this does not convey much information to me.
» The text "Order while you wait" has been taken from the metadata
description of the page( as far as I know) and the title "Starbucks" *has
been taken from the *title tag.

Now, say if I can custom define these parameters, for example like this

[image]

Here, I custom defined the text of the same starbucks URL that my phone's
physical web scanned for.

This adds for relevancy to the URL. A user gets a clear message. Also, it
allows the stores to convey an effective contextual message.

This is possible when you use ReactJS and JSX?, because only you have one HTML file and always show the title default that is in this html, even if you change it with document.title = "other title" in the notification show the first and not the new title

Answer (score 1):

The text shown in the Physical Web notification is strictly given by the target website and you can influence it only there.

The Chrome is actually [not analyzing](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/privacy/whitepaper.html#physical-web) the target website. Its a Google server (Physical Web Service) that analysis it and this one provides information to Chrome. You seem to need changing the title instantly and often. So be careful about caching of already resolved webs on the server.

The website analysis does not execute any Javascript. It takes only what is written in HTML directly. So the trick with document.title wont work.

But there is a different way how to get the notifications. Look at the [Google Nearby Notifications](https://developers.google.com/nearby/notifications/overview). In summary this works based on Eddystone-UID. You register your UID with the service and configure to redirect to target website. But in the configuration you can specify the title and description. Look at the mentioned page for the details.

Comment: but in your case, I need a native app for get the notifications? because I use react js and we do not want to use native app, is there any way to do without native app?

Comment: You actually don't need native app for Nearby Notifications. These are shown by Google Play Services which is installed on every Android. Unfortunately there is no iOS support yet (AFAIK). The second problem is that you are depending on the Play Services implementation about scanning frequency. And that is pretty battery conservative. And it can change with every version. So it can take much longer to detect the beacon than you spend in Starbucks...